# Content View within Table View Cell won't stretch in Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

In Xcode 7, the Content View within a Table View Cell will not consume the whole horizontal space as it did in Xcode 6.4. Minimal example:

1. New File > iOS > Source > Cocoa Touch Class
2. Create a class inheriting from `UITableViewCell` and let Xcode create the XIB file (iPad)
3. Set a accessiory for the view cell (actually not required)

In Xcode 6.4, the interface builder will render the control like this:

[image: Cell in Xcode 6]

When loading the very same project in Xcode 7 (or creating the control from scratch, doesn't matter), the cell will be rendered like this:

[image: Cell in Xcode 7]

The Content View doesn't consume the full horizontal width here. I tried all kinds of properties and constraints, but I didn't manage to get the Content View to stretch. Resizing the whole cell doesn't work as the inner view is somehow bound to the width of the control (with some minimum width at 440px, as it seems).

Is there a way to configure the control to behave as it did in Xcode 6.4?

Comment: ohh I alos see there is also a separator line in that xib!!! Is it provided in xcode 7?

Comment: The seperator is added by the `Default Insets` used for the `Seperator` property, but removing this won't change the behavior described above.